# Web Application is very slow due to database exist in different network

Tags: database

I have hosted My Apache Web Application in my Local Network Server, but the Database PostgreSQL Server is in a publicly hosted cloud Server. So the Application access is very slow for employees. If I host my web server itself in Cloud Server, I should enable Internet connection (need to enable Gateway, even I only enable access to this particular URL in Firewall there will be lots other security risks) in all employee's systems in LAN to access hosted Web Application.

**Is there any solution to connect and fetch data from my Remote Database server very fast?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using an web API to access the Database? You could make a C# API in Azure and user their Database system.

Comment: I think this is better suited for Server Fault.

Comment: no Web API for connecting database..using normal method by using pdo_pgsql db adapter..  My Server is Linux...